# Overlay two controls

Tags: .net, wpf, layout

I started to make some thing in WPF and I have a question. I think the answer might be easy and even obvious, but somehow...

I have two controls on a form enclosed by a grid. I want two position the second control above the first one (it's transparent). Coming from WinForms development that isn't that hard, so it won't be in WPF. But I don't get the point...

Sascha

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Either the `Grid` and `Canvas` controls would do what you wanted.

For most cases I'd recommend using the `Grid` to overlay elements, as you can also control how they resize easily.  They'll stack in the order you define them (last defined at the top).

Try something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue"/>
    <Ellipse Fill="Red"/>
</Grid>
```

BTW - learning XAML is much easier to do in an interactive tool like [Kaxaml](http://www.kaxaml.com/).

Comment: That functions well for rectangle and ellipse. The control to be overlayed would be a webbrowser control. For this I replaced Rectangle through Webbrowser with the result that the ellipse isn't shown anymore.

Comment: Got it with a browser running

Comment: Glad it's working for you.  I seriously recommend tinkering with Kaxaml to learn the ins and outs of WPF.

Answer (score 6):

If I am getting you correctly , just put the control in the reverse order inside the Grid. The order determines the Z-Index of the control

```
  <Grid>
    <c:ControlFirst/>
    <c:ControlSecond/>        
  </Grid>
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for,
Last control will be on top of all other controls.

Thanks for this info man !!